# Helix P4V Server IGNORE file not working with P4V client

Tags: perforce, p4v

I setup a P4V server on my machine successfully and was able to set a P4IGNORE file.

To test this, I added a test.txt file to be ignore on add. When I add a test.txt file to my local repo and mark it for add it isn't ignored and gets pushed to the server. On the other hand when I p4 add -f test.txt it will work and say the file is ignored in the terminal. I have no idea why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

P4IGNORE is a client setting, not a server setting.  Your P4V client might not be configured to read your ignore file.

If you want server-side enforcement of which files go into the server, use either the protection table (which can be applied across all users) or the client view (which will apply any time you use that workspace, regardless of whether you're using `p4` or P4V or any other client app).

Comment: So there is no way I can enforce a ignore like structure with a protection table. So even if I enforce users to a folder I won't be able to black list what files they upload?

Comment: As stated, you *can* indeed enforce these rules via the protection table.  It was literally my first suggestion.  :)